# Pass parameters to activity and fragment in the same time

Tags: java, android

I have a main activity, from this main activity I want to do an intent to open other activity and pass parameters. This new activity has a layout with a nested fragment inside which behavior controls a fragment. Is it possible to pass parameters from the main activity to the new activity and to the fragment in the same time? How can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your new activity fragment will be called only after the activity created. so you can pass the params from the activity.

From activity to Activity pass params through intent extras

```
intent.putExtra ("paramname", "value")
```

From Activity to Fragment , pass a bundle through args

```
customFragment.setArguments(bundle)
```

Comment: So, I have to pass from main activity to new activity params and later from this new activity the params to the fragment?